# How to define global variable for JWT token from layout page to be available in any pages which requires authentication?

Tags: javascript

I am using ASP.NET Razor pages layout for my website. In this layout, I have the Login link and when I click it, it will open a modal and once authenticated, I will store the token in localStorage. This is the code:

`localStorage.setItem('x-auth-token', JSON.stringify(result));`

All these I have done with no issue. My vanilla javascript is in this layout page.

The minor issue now is how do I "define" this token variable so that I can use this token variable in any pages which requires authentication? I have tried using `const` and `var` in layout but when I load the individual page, the token variable is undefined. Should I create a global variable page in javascript to store this token and then export it so that any page can import it? I want to keep it DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Comment: There's no way to define a variable that lives beyond the page load cycle. Just load the data from local storage into whatever variable you want when you need it. Write a function if DRY is that meaningful to you.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks. Okay, then I will define the token for each page which needs it.